# Even numbers - beginner

Tags: c

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to create a program that will generate numbers made only from even digits, rounding up to the nearest such number.

Examples:

> 135 --> 200
>   2700 --> 2800

I have one code but whenever I try to print it, the number increments only for 1 because I print it in the `while` loop but whenever I try to print it out of the loop I dont get it out.

Here's the code, check it out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int a = 135;
    int cifra;
    int i = a;
    int n;

    while (i != 0) {
        cifra = i % 10;
        n = cifra;

        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            i /= 10;
        } else {
            ++a;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your problem ?  What exactly you want ? Please include the print statements in your code.

Comment: First of all this is infinite loop  & I do not understand how is it working for you ? Please give the precise information on what exactly you require ?

Comment: As I said, my goal is to print the nearest number bigger than "a" that is made only from EVEN numbers. In this case a = 135 so as an result I should get 200, because 2, 0 and 0 are even. If a was 1900 as a result I should've had 2000. I didn't include the print statement because I don't know where should I put it exactly, tbh :$

Comment: This can be done without brute forcing by iterating the number.

Comment: @AnthinoRusso,_print the nearest number bigger than "a" that is made only from EVEN numbers_: well I could not spot something similar to this in your original question.

Comment: There are several possible solutions. Do you actually need to generate these numbers "as numbers" or is printing the correct digits enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution does not work because you may need to propagate the oddness up by several powers of 10.

Here is a simple method:

- check each digit from the least significant to the most significant ;
- for every odd digit, bump the number to the next multiple of the corresponding power of 10. A pattern of `xx1yyy` becomes `xx2000` and a pattern of `x9yyy` becomes `X0000` where `X` may be odd and will be handled in the next iteration.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned next_even(unsigned n) {
    for (unsigned div = 1; div <= n; div *= 10) {
        unsigned digit = (n / div) % 10;
        if (digit & 1) {
            /* found an odd digit, bump number up to the
               next multiple of div */
            n = n - n % div + div;
        }
        if (div > UINT_MAX / 10) {
            /* Prevent wrap around.
               The result may be incorrect for numbers >= UINT_MAX / 10. */
            break;
        }
    }
    return n;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        unsigned n = strtoul(argv[i], NULL, 0);
        printf("%u -> %u\n", n, next_even(n));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the above method does not work for all unsigned values because of potential overflow.

Comment: Nice and clean. I think it would benefit from a textual description, though. The algorithm may not be clear for a beginner.

Comment: It fails for `2888896456`, must be a wrap-around. `4000000000` is representable in 32 unsigned bit.

Comment: @2501: correct! the algorithm fails when the number is too close to UINT_MAX. Fixing it makes to code less readable.

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful. Start with the number and check if every digit is even. If yes, it will come out of the loop and print the value else it will increment the number and do the same over again. It's kind of a infinite loop.

```
int value = 123;
while (value > 0) 
{
   int digit = value % 10;
   if(digit%2 == 0)
   {
      flag =true;
   }
   else
   {
     flag = false;
     value = value + 1;
     continue;
   }
   value /= 10;
}
printf("Value = %d",Value)
```

Comment: Your code does not answer the question, after fixing the typo, it would always print `Value = 0`.

Comment: Is the approach totally wrong or with some improvements, it can be corrected ?

Comment: Your approach can be improved to make it work: try computing the output value incrementally and deal with odd digits appropriately and you'll get there.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for helping me but I managed to get the solution about this problem myself.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int a;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    while (a > 0) {
        a++;
        int n = a;
        int cifra;
        int flag = 0;

        while (n > 0) {
            cifra = n % 10;
            if (cifra % 2 == 0) {
                flag = 1;
                n = n / 10;
            } else {
                flag = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag) {
            printf("%d", a);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This solution uses brute force, but works for most integers, albeit slowly in many cases.  Note that `while(a > 0)` is not an adequate test for overflow: if `a++` overflows the range of type `int`, the behavior is undefined.